# Why does this List<T> update when I modify a separate variable?

Tags: c#, list

So I'm currently writing a function to load some data from a folder of text files.

```
public void loadPatterns()
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("patterns/");
    Level pattern = new Level();
    List<char> row = new List<char>();
    List<List<char>> grid = new List<List<char>>();

    for(int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
    {
        var lines = File.ReadLines(files[i]);
        foreach(string line in lines)
        {
            foreach(char c in line)
            {
                row.Add(c);
            }
            grid.Add(row);
            row.Clear();
        }
        pattern.grid = grid;
        patterns.Add(pattern);
        grid.Clear();
    }
}
```

However at the moment once the `foreach(string line in lines)` loop finishes, the grid has a number of rows that are completely empty. After looking through the debugger, it seems that even after a single row has been added to the grid, the `row.Clear()` method will clear the data that has been added to the List as well as clearing the data in the local variable 'row'.

Why does this happen?

I'm primarily a C++ programmer, so apologies if I've missed something very obvious for someone more familiar with C#.

Comment: C# has reference semantics for containers, not value semantics.

Comment: yup, @milleniumbug is right.  you should call a new row inside the loop.  and why do you need Clear()?

Comment: Thanks for your help, Matthew's answer below worked. The clear is necessary because my text files have a 5 x 5 array of characters. The 'row' variable will contain each row in the text file, so it must be cleared after each row is finished or the 'row' variable will become one large string.

Although looking at it, I could make the grid a `List<string>` and simply add each line to the grid as a `string`. Traversing this string later will basically be the same as traversing a List of Chars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `grid.Add(row);` you are not adding a copy of the row to the grid. You are adding a reference to the row. Therefore, when you call `row.Clear()` you are clearing the row that is stored inside the grid.

To fix this, you need to create a new row for each row of the grid. To do that, move the declaration of `row` to just after `foreach(string line in lines)`:

```
 foreach(string line in lines)
 {
     var row = new List<char>();
     ...
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks for your help! Too used to everything being a copy in C++.

Answer (score 3):

you are clearing your list via `row.Clear()`. You should create a new `row` with `row = new List<char>()`

```
public void loadPatterns()
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("patterns/");
    Level pattern = new Level();
    List<char> row = new List<char>();
    List<List<char>> grid = new List<List<char>>();

    for(int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
    {
        var lines = File.ReadLines(files[i]);
        foreach(string line in lines)
        {
            foreach(char c in line)
            {
                row.Add(c);
            }
            grid.Add(row);
            row = new List<char>(); // <-
        }
        pattern.grid = grid;
        patterns.Add(pattern);
        grid.Clear();
    }
}
```